# appcompat text sizes vs the actual material guidelines

Tags: android, material-design

Not sure if i am missing something, but it seems that the text sizes that come with the design support library (com.android.support:design:22.2.1) don't seem to match the material design style guide, specifically for sub headers and list items.

In the style guide for subheadings, its says it should be 14sp:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/subheaders.html#subheaders-list-subheaders

But it seems that the subhead style used in TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead i think uses this value which is 16sp:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/dimens_material.xml#L53

Then also, in the style guide it says that the font for single-line list items should be 16sp, but in the style and dimens xml files, the only style/text size that i can find of 16sp is menu text or the subhead text above (which doesn't seem right, but maybe there is something else).

Obviously i can inherit styles and override the text sizes myself, but i was expecting the support design library to follow the guideline specs. Am I using the wrong styles or looking in the wrong place, or is that just the way it is?